# apex replay debugger - command 'sfdx.launch.replay.debugger.logfile' not found

Tags: apex, debug

Problem with launching apex replay debugger. Cant even launch.

---

I have in vsc Salesforce Extension Pack and work with it.

1. run SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger.
2. get debug logs.(level everywhere is finest and I chose breakPoint)
3. choose log file , right click and choose - launch apex replay debugger wiht current file. *and get nothing.*
4. open command pallete choose this command and get error message

   **command 'sfdx.launch.replay.debugger.logfile' not found**

.vscode/launch.json :

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Launch Apex Replay Debugger",
    "type": "apex-replay",
    "request": "launch",
    "logFile": "${command:AskForLogFileName}",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "trace": true
  }
]}
```

---

Help please to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not a scratch org but sandbox without DX. (forget to mention)

Comment: For me even the command SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger was not appearing even though I had the Salesforce extension pack (expanded) and work with it regularly. What worked for me was (for some reason unclear to me) - install Salesforce Extension pack (although I was supposed to have the expanded version already) then restart VSC

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My fix, I just reauthorize the org.
SFDX: Authorize an org.

After that, I'm able to turn on the replay debugger.
SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger.

Comment: The question was not about turning on the replay debugger, but about running it on a downloaded log file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue...  once you invoke "SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger." on your targeted salesforce org,  Login to your instance via the web browser, navigate to the "Debug Logs" section under setup.

Sort the debug logs by the date that the logs expire.  Ensure the logs are targeted at your user and not someone else.  If it is targeted at your user, make sure to run any apex test classes or activity as your user. Adjust the user to be your own and then try to download the logs.  It should then work

Comment: tried one more time. doesn't work(

Comment: This one worked for me.  I deleted all of the "User Trace Flags" and was finally able to turn on the replay logging (shows up as "ReplayDebuggerLevels1619793750797" in my "User Trace Flags" console).

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy to do all these commands manually, you can just click on "Run debugger" in VsCode SFDX Hardis extension, like explained in the video at the end of this article

[image]

https://medium.com/p/12237c0638b7

Disclaimer: My company is the author is this VsCode plugin